# Find a length of a line

Tags: calculus

Find the lenght of a line presented in polar coordinates

$r=e^{2\varphi}, (-1\leq\varphi\leq1)$

*Sorry for the probable mistranslation*

Am I supposed to use
$s=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{\varphi_1}^{\varphi_2}r^2(\varphi)\mathrm{d}\varphi$
?

Comment: I think you mean arc length, and the formula you wrote down is for the area. Here is a reference: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarArcLength.aspx Check out the blue box

Comment: So (for clarification), I should use:

$s = \int\limits_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{1+r^2} \mathrm{d}\varphi$

Comment: No, in the page imranfat linked to, instead of $1$ under the square root it reads $\left(\frac {dr}{d\phi}\right)^2$

Answer (score 2):

To find the lenght of an arc $r = r(\varphi),\ \varphi_1 \leq \varphi \leq \varphi_2$, in polar coordinates you should use the following formula

$$s = \int_{\varphi_1}^{\varphi_2} \sqrt{r^2(\varphi) + \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}\varphi} \right)^2}\ \mathrm{d}\varphi.$$

In your case $r = r(\varphi) = e^{2\varphi}$, $-1 \leq \varphi \leq1$, so $\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}\varphi} = 2e^{2\varphi}$, and thus

$$s = \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{r^2(\varphi) + \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}\varphi} \right)^2}\ \mathrm{d}\varphi = \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{e^{4\varphi} + 4e^{4\varphi}}\ \mathrm{d}\varphi.$$